# How do I structure my Mongoose schema to patch a user's input as an object within an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose, nested

My app allows users to select a date for a specific event.

Each "Event" document has a "group" field with an array of objects with users email and the dates they have selected.

I'm trying to patch a user's date input within an existing "Event" document. The schema for an "Event" is below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userDatesSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type:String},
    startDate: {type:String},
    endDate: {type:String},
},{
    timestamps: false
});

const eventSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    group: [userDatesSchema]
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
```

Here is what a document in the "Events" collection looks like:

```
_id:######################
   group:Array
      0:Object
         _id:#####################
         email:"testing@gmail.com"
         startDate:"2021-05-11T16:00:00.000Z"
         endDate:"2021-05-13T16:00:00.000Z"
name:"Event7"
createdAt:2021-05-07T00:51:17.704+00:00
updatedAt:2021-05-07T02:39:25.623+00:00
__v:0
```

The Mongoose query to patch the dates input a user has selected:

```
router.route('/update').patch((req,res)=>{
    const email = req.user.email;
    const startDate = req.body.startDate.startDate
    const endDate = req.body.endDate.endDate
    const userDates = {
        email,
        startDate,
        endDate
    }

Event.findOneAndUpdate({eventName: req.body.eventName}, {$push:{group: [userDates]}}, {new: true},(error, data)=>{
        if (error) {
            res.send(error);
            console.log("errt:", error)
          } else {
            res.send(data);
            console.log("result:", data)
          }
    })
})
```

Unfortunately, the way this patch is currently set up, a new object is created every time resulting in multiple objects for dates within the "group" field for a single user...

```
_id:######################
   group:Array
      0:Object
         _id:#####################
         email:"testing@gmail.com"
         startDate:"2021-05-11T16:00:00.000Z"
         endDate:"2021-05-13T16:00:00.000Z"
      1:Object
         _id:#####################
         email:"testing@gmail.com"
         startDate:"2021-06-19T16:00:00.000Z"
         endDate:"2021-06-22T16:00:00.000Z"
name:"Event7"
createdAt:2021-05-07T00:51:17.704+00:00
updatedAt:2021-05-07T02:39:25.623+00:00
__v:0
```

How do I patch the dates in the object that already exists for the user instead of creating a new object with the updated dates?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using `$push` which pushes a new document to the array. I would recommend getting the relevant Event document and updating the dates or adding a new userDates to the group array.

Comment: If I remove $push, dates are only stored for a single user. But you’re right, $push does result in another document in the array for the same user (neither have the desired result). Thank you for the response.

Comment: Yes, you will need to either find a way of conditionally updating the contents of a value in the `group` array, or get the `Event` document in question, then either add a new value if an element in `group` with a matching email isn't found, or update the dates if it is.